# How to implement PocketSphinx on windows via java

Tags: java, windows, desktop, pocketsphinx

Is there a way to use `pocketsphinx` in `java` using w`indows OS`??

I am seeking to use hot word listening which clearly can't be done with `sphinx4`.

Comment: Simple way, call pocketsphinx_continuous through Java Process and process the output.

Comment: I'am trying to run 'swig. java. test' in pocketSphinx zip folder, but it is giving "edu. cmu. Pocketphinx" package doesn't exist.. Please take a look at the zip folder and show me what to do

Comment: Have you compiled pocketsphinx on Window OS ?

Comment: Or see this example on Github using Java JNI
https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/java/test/DecoderTest.java

Comment: I'am trying to run that same example, but it keeps telling me package doesn't exist 'edu.cmu.pocketsphinx' I'am using the ZIP folder provided in the link you wrote.

Comment: First learn how to compile and load lib on Windows then try that example.